# How to restore deleted files from a GitHub repository?

Tags: file, github, restore

I accidently deleted my files from my local repository (I didn't even know that this would happen) I just started using github today and I wanted to share a few files, when I chose the option to "stop monitoring this repository" (or something like that) it deleted all the files in it and for the past several hours I am trying to restore them I used several recovery files softwares and none of them managed to find them I also researched in google about how I can restore deleted files from github and what I found led me to:

```
git log --diff-filter=D --summary
```

Which shows me all the deleted files and their paths, then I try to use:

```
git checkout -- bit checker.cs
```

With or without the full path the result is the same:

```
error: pathspec 'bit' did not match any file(s) known to git.
error: pathspec 'checker.cs' did not match any file(s) known to git.
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: I think you need to specify the sha1 commit on checkout.

Comment: And that tells me nothing, like I said today is my first day using github so can you be more specific? :)